# How are nanoseconds calculated in java.time.Instant?

Tags: java, java-8

The [Java 8 docs on java.time.Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) state:

> The range of an instant requires the storage of a number larger than a long. To achieve this, the class stores a long representing epoch-seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second, which will always be between 0 and 999,999,999.

As per the [System.currentTimeMillis() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--), the Java 8 clock only guarantees, at best, millisecond resolution:

> Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the accuracy of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger

If Java 8 only guarantees millisecond accuracy at best, how does Java calculate the `java.time.Instant` nanosecond-of-second value?

Comment: Immediately after it in the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime-- Also, `Instant` isn't necessarily used only to represent the current time, and it doesn't have to only be read from the system clock.

Comment: @kaya3 That does not tell me how the value is calculated.

Comment: It contradicts your statement that *"Java 8 only supports millisecond granularity at best"*.

Comment: @kaya3 I will update the post to say "accuracy"

Comment: It's not an issue of wording; Java 8 **does** provide greater than millisecond accuracy if the OS allows it to. The fact that `currentTimeMillis` doesn't do this doesn't mean that Java 8 doesn't do this; `currentTimeMillis` is just one method, and doesn't impose any limitations on what other methods (or the JVM as a whole) is able to do.

Comment: *Java 8 does provide greater than millisecond accuracy if the OS allows it to* @kaya3 Please show me your source on that.  I only know that to be true for Java 9+.

Comment: Data types representing time can be used for more purposes than just reading the system clock.

Comment: From the link I just posted: *This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().*

Comment: Your source to say that it *doesn't* is only the documentation for `System.currentTimeMillis` - besides that being only one method, not the whole language, the documentation for that method is unchanged between Java 8 and Java 9.

Comment: @kaya3 You said Java provides greater than millisecond accuracy if the OS allows it to, but the docs clearly state that resolution is only at least as good as currentTimeMillis().  "At least as good as" is a different guarantee than "greater than".

Comment: *if the OS allows it to* - conditional, "if". Obviously it cannot be better if there isn't a more accurate system clock.

Comment: @kaya3 Implementation-wise, there was [an increase in precision](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) from Java 8 to Java 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Instant` class just promises nanosecond *precision* (i.e. the value of `nanos` will be provided *in nanoseconds*).  It does *not* promise nanosecond *accuracy* (i.e. the value may not accurately represent the current number of nanoseconds).

A simple multiplier (as specified by the specific `SystemClock` class instance used) is all that is needed to convert whatever unit *can* be obtained to nanoseconds.

---

Other points:

The `System.currentTimeMillis` method's documentation you link does *not* say 'at best'; it just promises to do as well as it can.

Secondly, you can see the implementation of the method by following through the stack trace in (for example) `Instant.now()`.  On my machine's java 8 setup (Mac OS, JDK 1.8.0.241) this falls back to using the `SystemClock` class, which eventually uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `Instant.ofEpochMillis`.  In *that* method, you can see that it simply multiplies the 'epoch millis' by `1_000_000`.

This has changed in later versions of java however.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses `Clock` class to get current instant. `Clock.systemUTC()` return best available system clock instance which could return more precise timestamp.

That said, Java 8 on Windows uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a source so it returns millisecond-precise time. But that's not guaranteed and other implementations can provide more precise time.

Also note that `Instant` is not necessarily obtained by `Instant.now()` call. You can parse it from input data, for example, where nanosecond precision might be useful.

Comment: Please note that I am wondering how the nanosecond of second value is calculated for an Instant.  I am having trouble relating your answer to my query.

Comment: That is directly answered in the first sentence, isn't it? It uses the `Clock` class, which returns the best available system clock instance.

Comment: That is true.  How is the nanosecond-of-second value calculated for an Instant which does not use a clock capable of nanosecond accuracy?

Comment: It claims nanosecond _precision_ (i.e., it will give a value in nanoseconds).  It does not guarantee nanosecond accuracy.  In fact, very few (if any) OSes I know _do_ provide nanosecond accuracy.  It uses a multiplier from whatever value _is_ supported to scale this to nanoseconds.  So, if milliseconds are all that are supported, then it will set the nanoseconds to milliseconds multiplied by 1,000,000.

Comment: @BeUndead that looks like the answer I'm looking for.  If you could post this as a separate answer with a source, I'll be happy to close this question out.